# Is there any exception that catch(...) can handle while catch(exception& ex) cannot?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have searched a lot for the differences between these two types of handlers, but everyone said that `catch(...)` is a generic handler which catches everything.

I could not find any exception that one of them can handle and the other cannot. Even divide by zero, creates an exception that both of them cannot handle (floating point exception).

Can anyone give me a sample and explain clearly their difference? Which one of them should I use?

Comment: `if (i < 0) throw "Oh! my!!";`

Comment: Divide by zero doesn't throw an exception. `throw 5;` does, though.

Comment: So in normal application (throwing standard errors), they don't differ. right?

Comment: @Hurkyl AFAIK, on Windows, `catch(...)` will catch divide-by-zeroes, but there is *no type* T for which `catch(T ex)` will catch them.

Comment: @immibis: Hrm. I suppose undefined behavior is permitted to act that way!

Comment: @Hurkyl Indeed, undefined behaviour is often implementation-defined for some implementations.

Comment: C++ isn't Java. Exceptions don't have to be types derived from `std::exception`.

Comment: Why did you tag this question by "c++11"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any exception that `catch(...)` can handle while `catch(exception& ex)` cannot?

Yes, any exception that is not, or not derived from, `std::exception` will not be caught by `catch(exception&)`. For example; `throw 42;` will be caught by `catch(...)`, but not `catch(exception&)`.

A `throw exception();` can be caught by either; the first handler is chosen. The `catch(...)` should be the last handler.

> Even divide by zero, creates an exception which both of them cannot handle (floating point exception)...

Visual Studio has two modes of exception handling; synchronous (`/EHsc`) and asynchronous (`/EHa`). For the synchronous handling, both `catch(...)` and `catch(exception&)` will only catch C++ exceptions; i.e. those thrown with a `throw xyz;`. For the asynchronous handling, access violations etc. can be caught with `catch(...)`.

VS also offers a function [`_set_se_translator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx) that can be used to "translate" or handle the Win32 exceptions. Typically the function is used to translate the Win32 exception to a C++ exception (derived from `exception`) that can be handled by a `catch(exception&)`.

A sample of what the translation could look like (some detail is omitted for brevity);

```
struct seh_exception : std::runtime_error {
    //...
};

struct access_violation : seh_exception {
    //...   
};

struct unspecified_seh_exception : seh_exception {
    //...
};

void translation_function(unsigned int code, ::EXCEPTION_POINTERS* info)
{
    switch (code) {
    case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
        throw access_violation();
        break;
    // more cases for other exception codes
    };

    throw unspecified_seh_exception();
}
```

> Which one of them should I use?

You should use the one that you can do something with. If all exceptions result in the same handling by your code, then use `catch(...)`. If your code needs to handle the exceptions separately, then you should have a handler for each exception that is expected.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, any exception that is of a type that doesn't have `std::exception` as its base class will not be caught by `catch(std::exception& ex)`.

For example,

`struct foo {};`

`throw foo();`

will be caught by `catch (...)`, and not by `std::exception`.

Answer (score 5):

You are allowed to throw pretty much anything (e.g an `int`), and `catch(...)` will catch anything. `catch(exception&)` will only catch `exception` or derived types.

Answer (score 3):

`catch(...){}` is catching all exceptions. `catch(std::exception& ex){}` is catching all exceptions with `std::exception` as a base class.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch